# how to rename the acquia marina theme in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am already install drupal in my localhost after that i want to add acquia marina theme. in side the sites/all/themes/acquia_marina.i want to rename the "acquia_marina" to "drupal_theme7". please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that Acquia isn't too far removed from a standard Drupal installation, you will need to rename the theme folder and the .info file in this folder to match it. You can also edit this file to change the name of the theme as it appears in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

go to `sites->all->themes->YOUR_THEME NAME`.

Rename the acquia_marina folder to drupal_theme_7.

Then change EVERY instance of 'acquia_marina' to 'drupal_theme_7'. This includes the .info file and if there is a `template.php` file every 'acquia_marina' needs to be changed to 'drupal_theme_7'.

For example change:

```
function acquia_marina_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
```

to:

```
function drupal_theme_7_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not be *renaming* themes at all. What you should instead be doing is creating a sub-theme of Acquia Marina and modifying that instead. Read through [this handbook](http://drupal.org/node/225125) page for more information.